# What does the "in" keyword in Lua do?

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua

I know it's usually combined with a *`for i,v in pairs() do`* loop (or `ipairs`, or even `next`) but what exactly is `in`?

**Just to clarify, I know how to use it, I just don't know the logic behind it, how does it work/what does it return?**

Comment: Syntax. http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8

Comment: @Etan Sorry, perhaps I didn't explain properly. I understand how to use it, I wanna know how it works though.

Comment: It doesn't "work". It doesn't do anything. It is syntax.

Comment: What do you mean? If it didn't do anything why isn't it just *for i,v pairs(tab) do*

Comment: It could be. It just isn't. It reads better with "in".

Comment: @Etan Are you serious? That's it? But the other keywords I know do things. local makes the next variable local, do behind a new scope, why don't in do anything?

Comment: Yes. I'm serious. And because those have a function and provide a feature. This doesn't. `,` and `;` and whitespace don't *do* anything either but they are syntactically important.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lua's `in` is not a function or a variable.  It's a part of the syntax for flow control.  You can't replace it, you can't copy it, you can't even refer to it.  It's rather like parentheses: a syntactic construct which has meaning for how a program is parsed, but which cannot be referred to within the program.

It doesn't "return" anything.  It doesn't have "logic."  It's more like a placeholder, or punctuation.

Comment: it should also be mentioned that the same is true for `do-end`

Comment: This just changes the question to *'How do `for in` loops work?'*

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't do anything. It is syntax. It isn't a function. It isn't an opcode. It isn't a language feature. It is purely syntactical.

See the [`forlist`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lparser.c.html#forlist) function in `lparser.c`:

```
static void forlist (LexState *ls, TString *indexname) {
  /* forlist -> NAME {,NAME} IN explist1 forbody */
  FuncState *fs = ls->fs;
  expdesc e;
  int nvars = 0;
  int line;
  int base = fs->freereg;
  /* create control variables */
  new_localvarliteral(ls, "(for generator)", nvars++);
  new_localvarliteral(ls, "(for state)", nvars++);
  new_localvarliteral(ls, "(for control)", nvars++);
  /* create declared variables */
  new_localvar(ls, indexname, nvars++);
  while (testnext(ls, ','))
    new_localvar(ls, str_checkname(ls), nvars++);
  checknext(ls, TK_IN);
  line = ls->linenumber;
  adjust_assign(ls, 3, explist1(ls, &e), &e);
  luaK_checkstack(fs, 3);  /* extra space to call generator */
  forbody(ls, base, line, nvars - 3, 0);
}
```

Create the control variables.
Handle the local variables in the comma list.
Check that the next token is [`TK_IN`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/llex.h.html#TK_IN) which maps to [`luaX_tokens`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/llex.c.html#luaX_tokens).